# Как удалить привязку аккаунта facebook от андроид приложения. что-бы при нажатии на кнопку "войти через facebook" снова появилось меню выбора аккаунта

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-api, logout

В андроид приложении в `Activity` реализовал `login` по кнопке ***"Войти через facebook"***.
Когда входил первый раз - то появилось окно для ввода данных (выбора аккаунта под которым хочу войти).

При дальнейших попытках входа, уже нет формы выбора аккаунта, а только фразы типа:

> Ранее вы входили в приложение с помощью Facebook.
>   Желаете продолжить?

Из вариантов выбора есть только `Продолжить` и `Отменить`.

Разлогиниваюсь таким методом:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

Понимаю что произошла привязка конкретного аккаунта `facebook` к приложению.
Но как ее правильно снять - не могу найти информацию.

Подскажите, как сделать `logout` с **`facebook`** так, чтобы при следующем входе через кнопку ***"Войти через facebook"*** снова появилось меню выбора аккаунта (ну или же форма логина)?

Comment: Надо войти через десктоп в Facebook и удалить из списка доверенных приложений ваше приложение

Comment: @Barmaley Это нужно делать каждый раз после логина пользователя? И я так понимаю это должен делать пользователь?

Comment: Привязка приложение-Facebook сохраняется на сервере Facebook - так что это должен делать юзер

Comment: @Barmaley А есть вариант это делать в приложении программно? Может какой то запрос отправлять на сервер фб, что юзер хочет деавторизироваться в приложении? А то получается что если захочешь зайти под другим аккаунтом- то придется тучу действий делать. О которых, большинство даже и не знает.